# For Loop in R - How to use previously created value

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, data.table

I am using the following for loop within an if statement for my data.table object.

```
if (condition== "xxxx"){
    i=NULL
    for (i in seq(1,length(unique(object$year)),1)) {
      object[GDP>=xxxxx,value:=(value)*(0.9),by=c("iso")]
      i=i+1
    } else if .......
.
.
.
  } else{}
```

So what I want to do is: I want to check in every year in my data.table object if the GDP is larger than a certain predefined number and if so then I want to update the column value by multiplying it by 0.9. Now the problem is if I execute this loop the loop works and everything but I do not update the previous value but it always takes the "default" value which leads to the incident, that all of my values are the same from the year on which exceeds my predefined GDP number.
So my question is: How to address my previously calculated value in a loop?
So I want the values in the column "value" so slowly decline over time.

Illustration:
What I want:

```
2020,xxxxx, 0.5
2025,xxxxx(predefined threshold reached ), 0.5*0.9(=0.45)
2030,xxxxx(predefined threshold reached), 0.45*0.9(0.405)
2035,xxxxx(predefined threshold reached), 0.405*0.9.......
.
.
.
```

What I get:

```
2025,xxxxx(predefined threshold reached ), 0.5*0.9(=0.45)
2030,xxxxx(predefined threshold reached ), 0.5*0.9(=0.45)
2035,xxxxx(predefined threshold reached ), 0.5*0.9(=0.45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
# "For every country,"
for (j in unique(object$iso)) {

    # "each year..." (i.e., for every year...)
    for (i in unique(object$year[object$iso == j])) { 
        
        # "...if the GDP ['GDP_cap' in that year] is larger than a certain predefined number [i.e., 45000]..."
        if (object$GDP_cap[object$iso == j & object$year == i] > 45000) { 
            
            # "...then I want to update the ['eps'] column value by multiplying it [and all the 'eps' values in the coming years] by 0.9."
            object$eps[object$iso == j & object$year >= i] <- object$eps[object$iso == j & object$year >= i] * 0.9 
        }
    }
}
```

**Validation Test**

Here is a smaller sample data to try:

```r
object <- object <- data.frame(
    iso = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), 
    year = c(2001:2002, 2001:2003), 
    GDP_cap = c(1:2, 5:7), 
    eps = 1)

object
#  iso year GDP_cap eps
#1   A 2001       1   1
#2   A 2002       2   1
#3   B 2001       5   1
#4   B 2002       6   1
#5   B 2003       7   1


# for every iso...
for (j in unique(object$iso)) { 

    # for every year (in that iso)...
    for (i in unique(object$year[object$iso == j])) { 
        
        # if GDP_cap (in that iso and year) > 1...
        if (object$GDP_cap[object$iso == j & object$year == i] > 1) { 

            # then apply half-life decay to eps (in that iso and year as well as all coming years)
            object$eps[object$iso == j & object$year >= i] <- object$eps[object$iso == j & object$year >= i] * 0.5 
        }
    }
}

object
#  iso year GDP_cap   eps
#1   A 2001       1 1.000
#2   A 2002       2 0.500
#3   B 2001       5 0.500
#4   B 2002       6 0.250
#5   B 2003       7 0.125
```

I changed the decay rate here because it becomes easier to do mental math. 
You can see that the "eps" decay is specific to each "iso". 
`object$eps[1]` does not change. 
`object$eps[2]` and `object$eps[3]` are first "eps" with "GDP_cap" greater than the assigned threshold in their respective "iso", so they are both 1x0.5<sup>1</sup>. 
`object$eps[4]` is the second for `object$iso == "B"` so it equals 1x0.5<sup>2</sup>. 
`object$eps[5]` is the third so it equals 1x0.5<sup>3</sup>.

Comment: Actually, I think you got it wrong. I do want to multiply the iso value by 0.9 and than in the next iteration, I want to multiply my previous value which I just got from my last iteration of the loop again whith 0.9. This should simulate an easy decay of this value.

Comment: Okay, please provide an example of your data. I don't know how your data looks.

Comment: In the data snapshot i just added to my question you can see the data structure. I just want to multiply the value "eps" with 0.9 and than do this again with my previous value and so on...

Comment: Okay, so what you're trying to say is, for every year, if GDP > GDP_cap (where the GDP_cap is not a fixed constant value), iso becomes iso*0.9 (i.e., loses 10%) AND all the iso's in the following years loses 10% as well?

Comment: Yes exactly but actually it's not the iso column, because the iso column represents different countries. It is the "eps" column which I need to adjust with this 10% loss per iteration once the GDP_cap value is above 45000. And also the GDP_cap value is given. So I just want to check if GDP_cap value > 45000 and if so than decrease eps by 10% for all the coming years...

Comment: Okay. I see why you want the for-loop. I'll remove the "simpler" solution that I have in this answer because it wouldn't apply in this case, but I'll edit my for-loop answer. Just keep in mind that these for-loops and if statements can be shaped to translate exactly what you say.

Comment: Hi somehow it does not change anything in the eps column if the GDP_cap value is higher than 45000. Are you sure the equality and inequality signs are correct?

Comment: Yeah, it works for my sample data. I'll add my sample data so you can try

Comment: I believe the problem is that with this code I do not take the different countries into account, which are represented by the column "iso". In my previous code, I used this ",by=c("iso")]"  to make sure the loop iterates through all available years for all available countries (iso). Could you also add the iso column to your sample data and test for different countries AND years.

Comment: So you want the calculations to be done for every country independently? I couldn't run your code because `object[GDP>=xxxxx,value:=(value)*(0.9),by=c("iso")]` doesn't work. `xxxxx` or `GDP` are not assigned variables.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear language. My data set basically has GDP data for all countries for all available years. So what I want to do is to let to loop run for each country (which are represented in the column "iso") and check whether in year i the GDP value is higher than 45000. And if so than i want the column "eps" to be updated with the function: eps [i-1(previous value)] *0.9. And then let this reduction go through all years. Than start with next country and so so...

Comment: I updated the solution. I think a key lesson here is to make sure the objective is really clear, including the all the necessary conditions.